# tkinter PhotoImage still not work for some PNG files

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, png, photoimage

> PhotoImage for images in PGM, PPM, GIF and PNG formats. The latter is supported starting with Tk 8.6.

Information about my environment,

- WIN10
- Python 3.6.0
- tkinter.TkVersion 8.6
- tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel') 8.6.6

I got some PNG files failed in following script

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

bg = PhotoImage(file='d:/Fandom.png')    # Failed here
bg_label = Label(root, image=bg)
bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Different PNG files can be downloaded from

- [Fandom.png](https://github.com/jason990420/PySimpleGUI-Projects/blob/master/pictures/Fandom.png)
- [duck.png](https://github.com/jason990420/PySimpleGUI-Projects/blob/master/pictures/duck.png)

File header for both files are the same `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` for PNG file. Both files can be shown without any problem under lot of softwares, lik windows File manager, ACDSEE, Paint, ...

Failure information for different PNG files

```
# Fandom.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: encountered an unsupported criticial chunk type "orNT"

# duck.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: encountered an unsupported criticial chunk type "eXIf"
```

Library `Pillow (PIL)` may help to work, but not the question here.

My questions are

- Do python 3.6.x with tkinter 8.6 support all PNG files ?
- If not, what format or version of PNG file get support ?

Comment: Both images work fine in my Python 3.9.2 with tkinter 8.6.9 in Windows 10.

Comment: I knew it  is OK on Python 3.9.x, but My question is for python 3.6.x in WIN 10.

Comment: Came here looking for SAME question... "does 8.6.6 not support some PNG files?"... It would seem that it has trouble with some such as - https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo-master-v3-TM.png.  Works fine on Python 3.7, but not 3.6.  Nice find Jason! (will document in new docs)

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/

Comment: I knew some different version Python may work, but its not my question here. Anyway, still thank you for your reply.